# 500 error while trying to enable CORS on POST with AWS API Gateway Proxy Integration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a response method that looks like this for my Lambda functions:

```
def respond(err, res=None):
    return {
        'statusCode': 400 if err else 200,
        'body': json.dumps(err) if err else json.dumps(res),
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': True,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }
```

When I test my endpoint with an OPTIONS request from Postman, I get a 500 internal server error. If I test it from the the API Gateway console, I get this additionally:

```
Execution log for request test-request
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: OPTIONS, Resource Path: /login
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: 
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Received response. Integration latency: 0 ms
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: 
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {}
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 200
Wed Jul 05 14:25:26 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I think I am returning all the right headers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it seems like you enjoy writing short Python code, so you can replace `json.dumps(err) if err else json.dumps(res)` with `json.dumps(err or res)`.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be with your headers, but with your mapping configuration based on this error `... configuration error: Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 200`. Can you attach your mapping configuration? Or are you using some kind of framework that does this for you? Are you using chalice?

Comment: I'm using API Gateway Lambda Proxy Integration. No frameworks besides that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the project completely with the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/), and CORS works now. I'm still not sure what was the issue. API Gateway seems very temperamental.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using lambda integration, but you seem to want the lambda proxy integration.

This error will be thrown if there is no default output configured on the integration response. Setup a method response and add a default mapping with the status code (or use lambda proxy integration).

Comment: I'm using lambda proxy integration. The functions work, the only thing not working is CORS.